# Linux shell tar zcvf bad written broke a folder in my server

Tags: linux, apache, tar

I was trying to compress a directory and I missed. I wrote:

```
tar zcvf wp-content/*
```

I don't know what happened. My folder wp-content seems to be fine but the server doesn't work (my website doesn't load). Here the an extract from apache error log:

```
[Fri Jun 12 16:42:54.034140 2015] [core:error] [pid 6771] [client 172.31.5.225:57994] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Jun 12 16:43:01.358329 2015] [:error] [pid 6875] [client 172.31.24.36:10591] PHP Warning:  include_once(/var/www/gremyo.com/htdocs/wp-content/sunrise.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/gremyo.com/htdocs/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 18
[Fri Jun 12 16:43:01.358361 2015] [:error] [pid 6875] [client 172.31.24.36:10591] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/gremyo.com/htdocs/wp-content/sunrise.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/gremyo.com/htdocs/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 18
```

Is there any way to undo the command I wrote badly? Any help?

edit: the output of the folder where I wrote the sentence

```
root@ip-172-31-11-223:/var/www/gremyo.com/htdocs# ls -l
total 220
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   418 Jun 10 18:22 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 17935 Jun 10 18:22 licencia.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 19545 Jun 10 18:22 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 15561 Jun 10 18:22 migrate_gremyo.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7360 Jun 10 19:33 readme.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 10 18:22 test
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  4951 Jun 10 18:22 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 10 18:22 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   271 Jun 10 18:22 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  5007 Jun 10 18:22 wp-comments-post.php
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 12 18:31 wp-content
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root      4096 Jun 12 15:57 wp-content.cp1
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 12 16:44 wp-content.repo
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3115 Jun 10 18:22 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 10 18:22 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2380 Jun 10 18:22 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3123 Jun 10 18:22 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 34241 Jun 10 18:22 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  8252 Jun 10 18:22 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 11048 Jun 10 18:22 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 25152 Jun 10 18:22 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  4035 Jun 10 18:22 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3032 Jun 10 18:22 xmlrpc.php
```

Comment: you didn't provide a filename for tar to write out to, so it used the **LAST**  file that your wildcard expanded to

Comment: @MarcB I think you meant "first"

Comment: How can I find that file my wildcard expanded to?

Comment: @thatotherguy: ah yeah, right. `tar target source`, basically

Comment: @miganml: `echo wp-content/*`

Comment: `echo wp-content/*` returns `wp-content/*` I don't understand why this echo

Comment: Is there any way to undo the command I wrote badly?

Comment: Restore the file from backup.  If you're lucky, you can move the file to another location, tar xfvz the file, and maybe the original file is in there.  But I wouldn't get my hopes up on that method.

Comment: @miganml You have to do it in the same directory you ran the tar command. It should show e.g. `wp-content/index.php wp-content/languages wp-content/plugins wp-content/themes` . Then you look at the first one, which in my case is `wp-content/index.php` but in your case can be something else. This is the file you need to restore or reinstall.

Comment: The problem is that after I wrote the command, I can't find the output

Comment: @thatotherguy I've done it but the error persists